# Allocating array of strings

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, dynamic-memory-allocation, c-strings, function-definition

Today i was having trouble allocating an array of arrays of char (an array of strings), i wrote this function to do so, but when printing the array, i had some problems with memory ( e.g. Segmentation Fault).
This was my attempt:

```
char **alloca_memoria(char **linguaggio, 
                      int n_sequenze, 
                      int *errore) 
{
    int i;        
    
    linguaggio = (char**) calloc( n_sequenze,
                                  sizeof(char*));
    
    if (linguaggio != NULL) 
    {      
        for ( i = 0;
              i < n_sequenze;
              i++ )
        {
            linguaggio[i] = (char*) calloc( MAX_SEQ , 
                                            sizeof(char));
            if ( linguaggio[i] == NULL ) 
                *errore = 1;
            else 
                *errore = 0;
        }
    }
    else 
        *errore = 1;

    return linguaggio; 
}
```

My aim was simply to make it allocate memory and return the value error to check if the allocation was successfull.
I can't really find what i'm doing wrong.

p.s. `n_sequenze` is the actual number of strings, `MAX_SEQ` is the max size of each string.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: @WhozCraig so using calloc in a function allocates memory just inside that function and not globally inside the program? So if i want the program to work i must allocate memory in the main function?

Comment: Nope. Read Vlad's answer, and probably get a good book on C.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the passed pointer linguaggio within the function then you need to pass it by reference. For example

```
char **alloca_memoria(char ***linguaggio, 
                      int n_sequenze, 
                      int *errore) 
{
    int i;        
    
    *linguaggio = (char**) calloc( n_sequenze,
                                  sizeof(char*));

    //...

    ( *linguaggio )[i] = (char*) calloc( MAX_SEQ , 
                                        sizeof(char));

    //...

    return *linguaggio;
}
```

Or it is better to declare the function like

```
char **alloca_memoria( int n_sequenze, int *errore)
{
    //... 
    char **linguaggio = (char**) calloc( n_sequenze,
                                  sizeof(char*));
    //...
```

And in the caller you can write

```
char **linguaggio = alloca_memoria( n_sequenze, &errore );
```

Comment: The parameter `linguaggio` is simply redundant and should be removed and a local variable should be used instead. The function returns a value. That's enough.

Comment: Was typing `***linguaggio` in the arguments a mistake, or do i need to pass it like that?

Comment: @Pinguiz The function parameter is declared correctly if you want to pass the pointer linguaggio declared like char **linguaggio; by reference to the function. That is the corresponding argument expression will be &linguaggio